# Failing ZIP deploy on Azure App Service for a ReactJS application

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy a ReactJS application to an Azure App Service. I have created my build (zip) folder from my build pipeline. When I try to deploy the zip to the App Service, however, I am getting the error below.

> **Error:** Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.

Comment: You have not mentioned the issue I think.

Comment: @rohit: Their error message was embedded in an image that wasn't properly linked. I've extracted the error message from the image and placed it in the question.

Comment: What deployment method are you using? E.g., is this using the Azure DevOps task? WebDeploy command line tool? Visual Studio with a `pubxml`? Can you include your deployment script here?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your depoly operation?

Answer (score 0):

Issue mitigated by deleting the resources and creating the webapp again.

We can also upload the ZIP file by dragging it to the file explorer area on the web page.

Here is the web page endpoint:

```
https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/ZipDeployUI
```